# Get distance field from $geoNear aggregation in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation command in my Spring project:

```
NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(longitude,latitude).maxDistance(distance).spherical(true);
agg = newAggregation(
                geoNear(query, "distance"),
                unwind("rate"),
                group("id")
                        .first("name").as("name")
                        .sum("$rate.general_rate").as("rate")
                        .count().as("num_rates")                                                                                        
        );
```

But when i made the mapped with my class, the distance field(from geoNear) is not exist. How can i pass in pipeline the distance to appear with others groups fields?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same :)

The answer is in your question..

> geoNear(query, "distance"),

The above line will look for the property *distance* (type Double in case of Point) in the class which you are trying to aggregate the result.

Eg., output
`"distance" : 420.82602810248557` (in [meters](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13540))